# How to figure out the optimal fetch size for the select query

Tags: oracle, memory, jdbc, fetch

In JDBC the default fetch size is 10, but I guess that's not the best fetch size when I have a million rows. I understand that a fetch size too low reduces performance, but also if the fetch size is too high.

How can I find the optimal size? And does this have an impact on the DB side, does it chew up a lot of memory?

Comment: It does not  chew up any memory. Oracle uses producer-consumer design pattern so resulting rows are generated on request(when you call fetch). Setting fetch size is supposed to reduce number of round-trips between the database and the application. I'm not sure about JDBC but at least in OCI you can also specify the size of receiving buffer in bytes(megabytes).

Comment: The default value is [zero](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int)).

Comment: here it says "By default, when Oracle JDBC executes a query, it receives the result set 10 rows at a time from the database cursor. 

"http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83724/resltse5.htm

Comment: JDBC doesn't have a default fetch size. It is up to the individual drivers. And there is no "optimal" fetch size. It depends on the query and how you process your results (and the database you use, the latency of the connection, etc). It is also a trade off between time and memory.

Comment: @EJP The value `0` for `fetchSize` means that the driver is free to choose his own default (although the driver is free to ignore your hint if you set it to anything other than `0` as well).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As with (almost) anything, the way to find the optimal size for a particular parameter is to benchmark the workload you're trying to optimize with different values of the parameter.  In this case, you'd need to run your code with different fetch size settings, evaluate the results, and pick the optimal setting.

In the vast majority of cases, people pick a fetch size of 100 or 1000 and that turns out to be a reasonably optimal setting.  The performance difference among values at that point are generally pretty minimal-- you would expect that most of the performance difference between runs was the result of normal random variation rather than being caused by changes in the fetch size.  If you're trying to get the last iota of performance for a particular workload in a particular configuration, you can certainly do that analysis.  For most folks, though, 100 or 1000 is good enough.

Answer (score 24):

If your rows are large then keep in mind that all the rows you fetch at once will have to be stored in the Java heap in the driver's internal buffers. In 12c, Oracle has VARCHAR(32k) columns, if you have 50 of those and they're full, that's 1,600,000 characters per row. Each character is 2 bytes in Java. So each row can take up to 3.2MB. If you're fetching rows 100 by 100 then you'll need 320MB of heap to store the data and that's just for one Statement. So you should only increase the row prefetch size for queries that fetch reasonably small rows (small in data size).

Answer (score 9):

The default value of JDBC fetch size property is **driver specific** and for Oracle driver it is 10 indeed.

For some queries fetch size should be larger, for some smaller.

I think a good idea is to set some **global** fetch size for whole project and **overwrite** it for some **individual queries** where it should be bigger.

Look at this article:

http://makejavafaster.blogspot.com/2015/06/jdbc-fetch-size-performance.html

there is description on how to set up fetch size globally and overwrite it for carefully selected queries using different approaches: Hibernate, JPA, Spring jdbc templates or core jdbc API. And some simple **benchmark for oracle** database.

As a rule of thumb you can:

- set fetchsize to **50 - 100** as global setting
- set fetchsize to **100 - 500** (or even more) for individual queries

Answer (score 0):

JDBC does have default prefetch size of 10. Check out 
OracleConnection.getDefaultRowPrefetch in [JDBC Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/toc.htm)

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

> How to figure out the optimal fetch size for the select query

1. Evaluate some maximal amount of memory (`bytesInMemory`)

   *4Mb, 8Mb or 16Mb are good starts.*
2. Evaluate the maximal size of each column in the query and sum up
   those sizes (`bytesPerRow`)

   *...*
3. Use this formula: `fetch_size = bytesInMemory / bytesPerRow`

   *You may adjust the formula result to have predictable values.*

Last words, test with different `bytesInMemory` values and/or different queries to appreciate the results in your application.

---

The above response was inspired by the (as of this writing attic) [Apache MetaModel project](https://attic.apache.org/projects/metamodel.html). They found an answer for this exact question. To do so, they built a class for calculating a fetch size given a maximal memory amount. This class is based on an Oracle whitepaper explaining [how Oracle JDBC drivers manage memory](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/memory.pdf).

Basically, the class is constructed with a maximal memory amount (`bytesInMemory`). Later, it is asked a fetch size for a `Query` (an Apache Metamodel class). The `Query` class helps find the number of bytes (`bytesPerRow`) a typical query results row would have. The fetch size is then calculated with the below formula:

```
fetch_size = bytesInMemory / bytesPerRow
```

*The fetch size is also adjusted to stay in this range : `[1,25000]`. Other adjustments are made along during the calculation of `bytesPerRow` but that's too much details for here.*

This class is named [FetchSizeCalculator](https://github.com/apache/metamodel/blob/97e6dbde4ad9c4979bd37025ce0a59bc743e9dbf/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/metamodel/jdbc/FetchSizeCalculator.java#L30). The link leads to the full source code.