# hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size or @QueryHints(@javax.persistence.QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.fetchSize", value="10")) not working

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

We are using Oracle DB with spring JPA(hibernate), for improved data fetch performance, I added `@QueryHints(@javax.persistence.QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.fetchSize", value=100000))` which improves performance dramatically.

Now when I want to change it to a smaller value, like 100 or 10, it is not working. It still can finish quickly, which is different behavior as before(wait for minutes to finish data fetch), but I sometimes get an "out of memory" issue. I tried to add hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size=10 in properties file and change the QueryHint, none of this is working. How to change the fetch size back?

env: linux

I'd expect I can change hibernate fetch size back to smaller value, like 10 or 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [default fetch size in oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/resltse5.htm) is already 10 records, so it's weird that you're having out of memory problems when adding this hint. Especially if 100000 does not pose a problem.

Some things I would do to pinpoint the problem and provide a solution:

**Barebone test your code**

Test the code responsible for your queries (probably your DAO) with a minimum overhead. I suspect the out of memory exception is more likely to be due to processing the database results and not the actual query + fetchsize.

So temporary alter your code to simply perform the query but don't do any mapping or other processing on it. Just make sure its done.

If this seems to "fix" your issue, you might have some performed on the data you receive that floods your memory.

**Update your dependencies**

If you're using maven (or gradle, or any other build tool) I'd suggest to update any update at least to the latest minor version (for instance 1.2.3 -> 1.2.9) this should not break anything but might fix some bugs.

**Don't go random with fetch sizes**

Check out [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730383/how-to-figure-out-the-optimal-fetch-size-for-the-select-query) to decide what a good fetch-size might be for your situation.