# HIbernate Criteria Query performance issue for deep joins

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I am facing a performance issue with hibernate criteria query involving deep joins.
When I execute the query generated by hibernate directly in database, results are returned within seconds.
Through hibernate it takes time some what exponential to the size of result. If there is 10 result then it takes 1 sec. If there is around 500 results then it goes to 15 sec and if more than 1000 then it takes around 30 sec and it goes like that.

I have put below the query generated by hibernate and the Java code I am using. In the logs below you can see after printing the query, results are returned after 30 sec.
I am using a tuple query in hibernate and using a result transformer to map results to DTOs.
Hibernate version is 5.3.7

I have enabled hibernate debug to get some details and the time is taken at place hibernate is looping through the result sets as I put below.
6465 records are fetched and hibernate takes nearly 30 sec to loop through each result set I think.
Is this normal?

I have replaced the actual table names below with dummy table names as this is part of client code.

Generated Query

```
12:12:25.644 INFO  query starts at Thu Apr 15 12:12:25 CEST 2021
Hibernate: 
    select
        table1_."table1_id" as col_0_0_,
        table4_."table4_id" as col_1_0_,
        table5_."table5_id" as col_2_0_,
        table5_."table5_col3" as col_3_0_,
        table5_."table5_col4" as col_4_0_,
        table6_."table6_id" as col_5_0_,
        table6_."table6_col6" as col_6_0_,
        table6_."table6_col7" as col_7_0_,
        table7_."table7_col8" as col_8_0_,
        table7_."table7_col9" as col_9_0_,
        table7_."table7_col10" as col_10_0_ 
    from
        "TABLE_1" table1_ 
    inner join
        "TABLE_2" table2_ 
            on table1_."table1_id"=table2_."table1_id" 
    inner join
        "TABLE_3" table3_ 
            on table2_."table3_id"=table3_."table3_id" 
    inner join
        "TABLE_4" table4_ 
            on table3_."table3_id"=table4_."table3_id" 
    inner join
        "TABLE_5" table5_ 
            on table4_."table5_id"=table5_."table5_id" 
    inner join
        "TABLE_6" table6_ 
            on table4_."table4_id"=table6_."table4_id" 
    inner join
        "TABLE_7" table7_ 
            on table6_."table7_id"=table7_."table7_id" 
    where
        table1_."CREATION_DATE">? 
        and table1_."CREATION_DATE"<? 
        and (
            table1_."col1" is not null
        ) 
        and (
            table1_."col2" is not null
        ) 
        and (
            table4_."col1" is null
        ) 
        and table1_."col2"=?
        
12:12:55.741 INFO  Total time taken for querying 30 Seconds 
12:12:55.743 INFO  total size: 2023
```

Debug logs

```
10:48:03.944 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader Result set row: 0
10:48:03.944 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader Result row: 
10:48:03.944 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader Result set row: 1
...................................................
10:48:34.136 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader Result set row: 6465
10:48:34.136 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader Result row:
```

Java code

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteriaQuery = builder.createTupleQuery();
Root<Table1> root = criteriaQuery.from(Table1.class);
Join<Table1, Table3> table3Join = root.join("table3s", JoinType.INNER);
Join<Table3, Table4> table4Join = table3Join.join("table4s", JoinType.INNER);
Join<Table4, Table5> table5Join = table4Join.join("table5", JoinType.INNER);
Join<Table4, Table6> table6Join = table4Join.join("table6s", JoinType.INNER);
Join<Table6, Table7> table7Join = table6Join.join("table5", JoinType.INNER);

ParameterExpression<Date> startDateParamBuilder = builder.parameter(Date.class);
ParameterExpression<Date> endDateParamBuilder = builder.parameter(Date.class);
ParameterExpression<Boolean> col3ParamBuilder = builder.parameter(Boolean.class);

List<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
conditions.add(builder.greaterThan(root.get("creationDate"), startDateParamBuilder));
conditions.add(builder.lessThan(root.get("creationDate"), endDateParamBuilder));
conditions.add(builder.isNotNull(root.get("condition1")));
conditions.add(builder.isNotNull(root.get("condition2")));
conditions.add(builder.isNull(table4Join.get("condition3")));

criteriaQuery
        .multiselect(
                root.get("id"),
                table4Join.get("id"),
                table5Join.get("id"),
                table5Join.get("col3"),
                table5Join.get("col4"),
                table6Join.get("id"),
                table6Join.get("col6"),
                table6Join.get("col7"),
                table7Join.get("col8"),
                table7Join.get("col9"),
                table7Join.get("col10"))
        .where(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
query.setParameter(startDateParamBuilder, startDate);
query.setParameter(endDateParamBuilder, endDate);

Table1SearchResultTransformer Table1SearchResultTransformer = new Table1SearchResultTransformer();
query.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class).setResultTransformer(Table1SearchResultTransformer).getResultList();
```

Comment: Is the above query the only one executed? If so, this is really a SQL question. Try `EXPLAIN`ing the query to see where the time went

Comment: As I mentioned the time is taken only when hibernate criteria query is executed from code. I have checked the explain plan directly firing query in database, that has no problem and results are returned in milliseconds. This is not an sql problem.

Comment: Added the hibernate debug logs where all the time is spend..

Comment: Did you try to remove your `Table1SearchResultTransformer` yet to see if that is the problem?

Comment: The transforming starts after the debug logs I put earlier (org.hibernate.loader.Loader Result row). Transformer is quick. It takes around 20 ms for 100 rows.

Comment: ...............................
10:42:07.175 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader Result set row: 6435
10:42:07.175 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader Result row: 
10:42:07.175 INFO  Table1SearchResultTransformer  Transforming results for request id 1002666
10:42:07.175 INFO  Table1SearchResultTransformer  Transforming results for request id 1002666
10:42:07.176 INFO  Table1SearchResultTransformer  Transforming results for request id 1002666
..................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. The performance problem was mainly due to the oracle default fetch size - 10 records. This was causing too many database round trips in my case for large number of results.

So I set the fetch size to about 1000 and there was a drastic change in the response time. The response time has now reduced to 3 sec for 6000 records

```
query.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class).setFetchSize(1000)
```

There is some insights on correct use of fetch size in this post
[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258890/hibernate-jdbc-fetch-size-or-queryhintsjavax-persistence-queryhintname-org)